# Maritime routing considering high detail depth data

Tags: postgis, routing, s-57, maritime-map

[image: depth polygons derived from S57 data]

I'm looking for ways to find routes between points considering high detail depth data. In the screenshot I presented here the size of the depth polygons can be down to a few square metres. My overall challenge is to find the shortest compliant route for a boat  with a certain draft - usually pleasure crafts with 0.5 - 3 metres. In this regard, I have tried different kinds of implementations of [grid approaches](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3pKSczjtrs&ab_channel=CrunchyData) using various sized cells which doesn't yield the optimal route as it will follow the grid shape and simplification of the output is prone to error, i.e. it may then again intersect with too shallow water. Additionally, I enriched the [grid with AIS data](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.00090.pdf) to influence the costing for certain regions which had a positive effect but then again didn't produce the result I would expect by drawing a simple route using paper charts.

I am fairly certain that the classical Dijkstra approach for near coastal maritime waters can't be used using a preprocessed graph unless I am missing something. After some further research I found some interesting publications using genetic algorithms to produce routes. One of them uses a so-called [initial route generation approach](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10732-020-09449-7#Sec9) which basically connects source and destination and recursively moves the centroid of the linestring in either direction until it doesn't intersect with land mass. Extending this idea with depth areas does actually work, however it again doesn't necessarily produce the shortest path.

The objective seems to be so simple but finding a solution isn't. I am currently looking for further ideas or even input to the approaches I have presented here.

Comment: Dijkstra is a linear (vector) solving approach, inappropriate for continuous (raster) modeling. So much effort has been made to produce charts that detail channels, which you don't mention al all. A continuous cost surface where channels have zero cost and anything near an obstruction has 32k cost should suffice.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I got it wrong all along. One follow up question: I'm currently giving this recipe utilising sklearn.graph a shot - do you see anything off the top of your head that could not work with it https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#create-least-cost-path ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no opinion at all on that topic.